# Renaming files recursively and moving them inside one single directory

Tags: centos5, rename, recursive

I have a project with 500k users in CentOS. The picture file/directory structure was setup like this (yeah... i know):

- `user/0070/` this is the user ID / 1000, so that all users in the range of [70000-70999] are inside this directory
- `user/0070/70909/` this is the user ID
- `user/0070/70909/p.jpg` profile picture (100x100)
- `user/0070/70909/x.jpg` full size picture

I'm moving everything to a CDN, so I need to convert that structure into this:

- `user/70909.p.jpg` profile picture (100x100)
- `user/70909.x.jpg` full size picture

Of course, the only way to achieve that in a period of time is to execute a script that renames and moves all files inside one single directory. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @janos done! :)

Comment: you **really** don't want 1M files in a single folder

Comment: @JamesRyan do you suggest leaving them as they currently are?

Comment: They have probably been setup this way to make them manageable yes.  Surely it is trivial in any script to use the extra folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash:

```
cd user
for i in *; do
    for j in $i/*; do
        for k in $j/*; do
            mv $k `basename $j`.`basename $k`
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i'm gonna try this right now. this is the first time im going to execute a script in bash.